# Android: App crashes on Back Pressed - SurfaceView

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-canvas, surfaceview

I am working on an android app, and just created the background canvas. The app loads fine, but when I press the back button (i.e to close the app) - the app crashes. Looking at the logcat (see below) I get a NullPointerException. Anyone know a way I can fix this?

Here are my classes:

```
package pmm.antiaircraft1;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;

public class GameActivity extends Activity {

  private GameThread mGameThread;

  public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    mGameThread = ((GameView) findViewById(R.id.game)).getThread();
    mGameThread.createGraphics();
  }
}
```

```java
package pmm.antiaircraft1;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.util.DisplayMetrics;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;

public class GameThread extends Thread {
  private SurfaceHolder mSurfaceHolder;
  public DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
  private static Bitmap mBackgroundImage;
  public static Bitmap tankImg;
  public static Bitmap cannonImg;
  public static boolean mRun = false;
  private Tank tank;
  public static Resources res;

  public GameThread(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder, Context context, Handler handler) {
    mSurfaceHolder = surfaceHolder;
    Resources res = context.getResources();
    mBackgroundImage = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, R.drawable.background);
    tankImg = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, R.drawable.tank);
    cannonImg = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, R.drawable.cannon);
  }

  @
  Override
  public void run() {
    while (mRun) {
      Canvas c = null;
      try {
        c = mSurfaceHolder.lockCanvas(null);
        synchronized(mSurfaceHolder) {
          draw(c);
        }
      } finally {
        if (c != null) {
          mSurfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(c);
        }
      }
    }
  }

  public void setRunning(boolean b) {
    mRun = b;
  }

  private void draw(Canvas canvas) {
    canvas.drawBitmap(mBackgroundImage, 0, 0, null);
    tank.draw(canvas);
  }

  public void createGraphics() {
    mBackgroundImage = Bitmap.createBitmap(mBackgroundImage);
    tank = new Tank();
  }
}
```

```java
package pmm.antiaircraft5;

import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;

public class GameView extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {
  private GameThread thread;

  public GameView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    SurfaceHolder holder = getHolder();
    holder.addCallback(this);
    thread = new GameThread(holder, context, null);
  }

  public GameThread getThread() {
    return thread;
  }

  public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {

    thread.setRunning(true);
    thread.start();

  }


  @
  Override
  public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width,
    int height) {}

  @
  Override
  public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    this.setWillNotDraw(false);

  }
}
```

```java
package pmm.antiaircraft1;

import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Matrix;

public class Tank {
    private static final int TANK_HEIGHT = 50;
    private static final int TANK_WIDTH = 50;
    private static final int TANK_TOP = 480 - TANK_HEIGHT;
    private static final int CANNON_WIDTH = 10;

    public Tank(){
        GameThread.tankImg=Bitmap.createBitmap(GameThread.tankImg);
        GameThread.cannonImg=Bitmap.createBitmap(GameThread.cannonImg);
    }

    public void draw(Canvas c) {
        c.drawBitmap(GameThread.tankImg, (320-TANK_WIDTH)/2, TANK_TOP, null);   
        Matrix m = new Matrix();
        m.postTranslate((320-CANNON_WIDTH)/2, TANK_TOP - 30);
        c.drawBitmap(GameThread.cannonImg, m, null);    
    }
}
```

Log output:

```
W/SurfaceView(400): CHECK surface infomation creating=false formatChanged=false sizeChanged=false visible=false visibleChanged=true surfaceChanged=true realSizeChanged=false redrawNeeded=false left=false top=false
**E/AndroidRuntime(400): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-88523
E/AndroidRuntime(400): java.lang.NullPointerException
E/AndroidRuntime(400): at pmm.antiaircraft1.GameThread.draw(GameThread.java:52)
E/AndroidRuntime(400): at pmm.antiaircraft1.GameThread.run(GameThread.java:37)**
W/SurfaceView(400): CHECK surface infomation creating=false formatChanged=false sizeChanged=false visible=false visibleChanged=false surfaceChanged=false realSizeChanged=false redrawNeeded=false left=false top=false
03-29 01:56:46.565: W/SurfaceView(400): CHECK surface infomation creating=false formatChanged=false sizeChanged=false visible=false visibleChanged=false surfaceChanged=false realSizeChanged=false redrawNeeded=false left=false top=false
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SurfaceView lifecycle is not exactly the same as the Activity lifecycle.  If you check the result of `lockCanvas()` in `run()`, and don't try to draw when it's null, you should be able to avoid the crashes without any visible glitches.

To do this more carefully, and avoid other potential problems, you need to use the Surface callbacks to track the current state.  An explanation can be found [in an appendix](https://source.android.com/devices/graphics/architecture.html#activity) to the graphics architecture document, and examples can be found in Grafika (e.g. the "[multi-surface test](https://github.com/google/grafika/blob/master/src/com/android/grafika/MultiSurfaceActivity.java)" activity).